# How to do automatic deploy to an existing server with octopus deploy

Tags: octopus-deploy

How do I create a trigger to make an automatic deploy to a already existing, healthy server with Octopus deploy?

I have created steps to create the package on the buildserver and created the release in Octopus, but I can't create a trigger to do the deployment itself.

We are using Octopus 3.4.12.

Answer (score 1):

From my understanding of the Octoups Deploy triggers this is not what they're designed for - but rather keeping various environments up-to-date.

I would suggest adding a step to the end of your build on the build server to automatically create the release and deploy it.  I use TeamCity and it's very straightforward using the Octopus Deploy plugin.  It should be possible with any build server even without a plugin, since you can always use the commandline tool `Octo.exe`.

Comment: I think you are right about the triggers, and that they are not for this. I think the "correct"/Octopus way of doing this is to create a lifecycle that has automatic deployment. Check this: https://octopus.com/docs/key-concepts/lifecycles#Lifecycles-LifecyclePhases

Comment: Yes this is a good solution. Now I remember I looked at this however it wasn't appropriate in my situation as I have multiple applications deploying to the same environment, and not all should have automatic deployment.. and I didn't want to create multiple lifecycles etc.  So I think this solution is good unless you need more fine-grained control.  Enjoy the continuous deployment!

Answer (score 1):

If your trigger is a machine or environmental event, eg another 'heathy server' comes online - use Triggers.

https://octopus.com/docs/deploying-applications/automatic-deployment-triggers

If your trigger is a new build of the software, eg TFS or TeamCity server build - use Lifecycles and adjust the first environment in the list.

https://octopus.com/docs/key-concepts/lifecycles